# cost splitter javascript app

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a cost splitter app for my roommates. I am explaining the app with an example. Suppose we are 4 members, there is a cost of 300, and 3 members (m1, m3, m4) participated in the expenditure (all have an equal share). Among them 2 members have paid the amount as follows: m3 paid 180 and m4 paid 120. Now the balance sheet will look like this:

```
m1(-100), m2(0), m3(+80), m4(+20)
```

I am not able to get all the form values properly and make the balance sheet.

```
<div>
    <table id="dashboard">
       <tr>
           <th>TOTAL</th>
           <th>member1</th>
           <th>member2</th>
           <th>member3</th>
           <th>member4</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td id="total"></td>
           <td id="bmem1">0</td>
           <td id="bmem2">0</td>
           <td id="bmem3">0</td>
           <td id="bmem4">0</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="newCostButton">
    <button id="showForm" href="#">Add New Cost</button>
</div>
<form id="elForm">
    <label>Cost:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cost" placeholder="Add new cost">

    <br>
        <label><b>Participants:</b></label><br>
        <span>member1</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Participant" value="member1">
        <span>member2</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Participant" value="member2">
        <span>member3</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Participant" value="member3">
        <span>member4</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Participant" value="member4">

    <br>
    <b>contributors:</b><br>
    member1
    <input class= "contributors" type="text" name="member1">
    member2
    <input class= "contributors" type="text" name="member2">
    member3
    <input  class= "contributors" type="text" name="member3">
    member4
    <input class= "contributors" type="text" name="member4">
    <input type="submit" id="cal" value="calculate"> 
</form> 
 <div id="doc"></div>
<script>
   $(function(){
var $newCostButton = $('#newCostButton');
var $elForm = $('#elForm');
var $cost = $('#cost');
$newCostButton.show();
$elForm.hide();
$newCostButton.on('click', function(){
    $newCostButton.hide();
    $elForm.show(); 
});
$('input:text').focus(function(){
    $(this).val("");
}); 
function cal(){
    var c = $cost.val();
    var part = $('input:checked');
    pCount = part.length;
    var d= parseInt(c/pCount); 
    var contributors = $('.contributor');
    var mem = [];
    contributors.each(function(){
        mem.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
    });
    console.log(mem);
    for(var i=0;i<pCount;i++){
        var r = mem[i]-d;
        console.log(r);
    }
}
 $elForm.on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    cal();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does something similar to what you are asking for. I simplified a few things like `.hide()` and `.show()`, but they're easy enough to add back. Hopefully something in here helps. If not, it was still a fun hour code challenge.

html:

```
<div>
    <table class="dashboard">
       <tr>
           <th>TOTAL</th>
           <th>member1</th><th>member2</th><th>member3</th<th>member4</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="newCost">
  <span>Cost:</span><input type="text" placeholder="Add New Cost">
  <button>Add New Cost</button>
</div>
<div class="participants">
  <p>Participants:</p>
  <span>member1</span><input type="checkbox">
  <span>member2</span><input type="checkbox">
  <span>member3</span><input type="checkbox">
  <span>member4</span><input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="contributors">
  <p>Contributors:</p>
  member1 <input type="text">
  member2 <input type="text">
  member3 <input type="text">
  member4 <input type="text">
</div>
<button class="calculate">calculate</button>
```

javascript:

```
String.prototype.toInt = function() { return parseInt(this, 10); };

$('.newCost button').on('click', function() {
    let newCost = $('.newCost input').val().toInt();
    $('.dashboard td')
    .each(function(index, td) {
        td.textContent = td.textContent.toInt() + (index ? newCost / 4 : newCost);      
    });
});

$('button.calculate').on('click', function() {
    $('.participants input').each(function(index){
    if (this.checked) {
        this.checked = false;
        let currentOwed = $(`.dashboard td:eq(${index + 1})`).text().toInt();
        let contributed = $(`.contributors input:eq(${index})`).val().toInt();
        let total = $('.dashboard td:eq(0)').text().toInt();

      $('.dashboard td:eq(0)').text(total -= contributed);
      $(`.dashboard td:eq(${index + 1})`).text(currentOwed -= contributed);
    }
  });
});

$('button').click(()=> { $('input[type=text]').val(''); });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wn7bbxjk/

Comment: You have misunderstood the problem statement. When a member doesn't participate, he doesn't have to pay for that cost.                               I have modified your solution for that situation. check my answer. thanks for the help.

Comment: Entirely possible. However, if you were able to understand the code and modify it to your needs, I'd say that's worth more than me just writing it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you import jquery

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

why don't you use excel or google sheets?

Comment: Maybe he wants a mobile web app that doesn't require third party software? Or he wants to host it so the roomates can use it without installing another app? Or he's just bored and wants to learn Javascript; that's what got me into it.

Comment: @Marc Frame I uploaded only the body part. So you are not able to see the jQuery import.

Comment: @ PoorlyWrittenCode You got me right. As I am learning javascript , i thought let build some useful app for myself. Its a kind of adventure for me.

Comment: @Sujoy Welcome to the community. One of the best ways to learn is to do.

Comment: ah I see, just wondering cause I recently created something similar for my roomates in google sheets.